# NonlinearModelFit with Discrete x variable

Tags: fitting

I have a dataset which is four observations taken in four discrete cases. I would like to use NonlinearModelFit in Mathematica to fit the data to a relatively complex function to predict these observations. The function is defined such that it takes in parameters and outputs 4 predictions. Is it possible to use NonlinearModelFit in a case where the "x" variable is discrete rather than continuous?

In more detail: let's say y=F(a,b,i) where a and b are the parameters I want to fit, and i=1,2,3,4 labels the observation in my data. My data is a list {data[[1]],data[[2]],data[[3]],data[[4]]}, and my function F outputs {y[[1]],y[[2]],y[[3]],y[[4]]}. Clearly there is no natural "x" variable that the NonlinearModelFit function generally expects. In fact, because the function F outputs the 4 predictions in the proper order, there isn't even any *need* to make F a function of i in the first place. How can I handle this?

For example, here is some toy code of my attempt:

```
simulate[a_, b_, i_] := Module[{A, vec},
  A = ConstantArray[0, {4, 2, 2}];
  A[[1, ;; , ;;]] = {{2*a, b}, {b, a}};
  A[[2, ;; , ;;]] = {{a^2, b^2}, {a^2, b^2}};
  A[[3, ;; , ;;]] = {{b, a}, {a, b}};
  A[[4, ;; , ;;]] = {{a^2 - b^2, b^2}, {a, b}};
  
  vec = {1, 3};
  out = {i, vec.A[[i, ;; , ;;]].vec}
  ]

data = {{1, 26.0}, {2, 79.0}, {3, 31.0}, {4, 39.0}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, simulate[a, b, i], {{a,0.9}, {b,2.25}}, i]
```

For this example, my "data" vector is exactly what would be calcualted if a = 1 and b = 2.5, and I'm trying to do a test to see if the code predicts these values as a sanity check.

Comment: It appears that want to estimate 3 parameters (a, b, and an error variance) with only 4 points.  Unless the error term is essentially zero, I think you're expecting too much for any software.  Also, if there is an order to the predictions you might have a 4th parameter characterizing serial correlation.  There's no reason why `i` can't be a "natural x variable".  Your dataset could look like `Transpose[{{1,2,3,4},y]`.  Giving a toy example would be helpful.

Comment: I have added some toy code to my example. My description is highly simplified, just to understand if this is possible. So of course in the end I will have more data than parameters, but I just want to understand the principle for now, so let's focus on *how* this is done, not *why*. It seems there is a problem assuming "i" can be my "x" variable, because this leads to infinite gradients, etc.

Comment: Many folks here can give you a much better answer when the *why* is at least briefly described.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `simulate` to use `Piecewise` results in giving just a single value (rather than currently a list) seems to fix things:

```
vec = {1, 3};
simulate[a_, b_, i_] := Piecewise[{{vec.{{2*a, b}, {b, a}}.vec, i == 1},
   {vec.{{a^2, b^2}, {a^2, b^2}}.vec, i == 2},
   {vec.{{b, a}, {a, b}}.vec, i == 3},
   {vec.{{a^2 - b^2, b^2}, {a, b}}.vec, i == 4}}]

data = {{1, 26.0}, {2, 79.0}, {3, 31.0}, {4, 39.0}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, simulate[a, b, i], {{a, 0.9}, {b, 2.25}}, i];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]